# Wordpress get attribute from a shortcode within a page

Tags: php, wordpress, email, shortcode

I'm building a wordpress contact form plugin that outputs a simple contact form when a shortcode is used. The shortcode has an attribute `recipient_email` which is the email address the user would like all emails to go to from the form. I am trying to get the value for recipient email in my php mailer file.

This is the html outputted by my shortcode with it's attributes:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'el_class' => '',
            'title' => '', 
            'subtitle' => '',
            'recipient_email' => '',
        ), $atts));

        $el_class = $this->getExtraClass($el_class);
        $css_class = apply_filters(VC_SHORTCODE_CUSTOM_CSS_FILTER_TAG,$el_class, $this->settings['base']);
        $subtitle = '<legend>'.$subtitle.'</legend>';           

        $output .= '<div class="contact-form '.$css_class.'" >';
        $output .= '<h4 class="form-title">'.$title.'</h4>';            

        $output .=  '<div id="contact">

        <div id="message"></div>

        <form method="post" action="'. VCPB_PLUGIN_URL . 'contact.php' .'" name="contactform" id="contactform">

        <fieldset>';

        $output .= $subtitle;

        $output .= '<label for="name" accesskey="U"><span class="required">*</span> Your Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" />

        <br />
        <label for="email" accesskey="E"><span class="required">*</span> Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" />

        <br />
        <label for="phone" accesskey="P"><span class="required">*</span> Phone</label>
        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" value="" />

        <br />
        <label for="comments" accesskey="C"><span class="required">*</span> Your message</label>
        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="5" id="comments" style="width: 350px;"></textarea>

        <p><span class="required">*</span> Are you human?</p>

        <label for="verify" accesskey="V">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 + 1 =</label>
        <input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" size="4" value="" style="width: 30px;" /><br /><br />

        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />';
        $output .= '</fieldset>

        </form>

</div>';          
        $output .= '</div>'; /* END .contact-form */
        return $output;
```

As you can see, the information from the form is sent to `contact.php` which processes the form and emails it out.

Here is the main part from my php mailer file (`contact.php`):

```
$address = "$recipient_email";
$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';
$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name, their message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

// Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

echo "<fieldset>";
echo "<div id='success_page'>";
echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</fieldset>";

} else {
echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

The top line here is what I am trying to fix:

```
$address = "$recipient_email";
```

I want `$recipient_email` to be the value that is entered into the shortcode. Can anyone hep me figure out how I would do this?

Comment: so did you create this shortcode?  where's the code that you use to output the html from the shortcode?

Comment: @manishie just added the whole of the shortcode code to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do that
either send the recipient by input type hidden (which is not a good option)

or

put the form action on the same page and not on contact.php
on same page you can use the shortcode_atts to get the recipient_email

Comment: Thanks for this, I was thinking combining the scripts was the way to go. What do I put as form action if I combine them?

Comment: put no form action.  that will submit the form to the same url.